# Dirac Measure (weak limit)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

I am wondering why Dirac measure is weak limit of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because for all $\varphi \in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$, $$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\varphi (x)f_r(x)\,\mathrm d x=\varphi (0)=\left<\varphi ,\delta _0\right>.$$